# Permission to war file in jboss wildfly docker container

Tags: docker, jboss, wildfly, permission-denied

I am using CentOS 7 . I have pull the image from docker hub

```
https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/wildfly/
```

and take war from the

```
https://github.com/arun-gupta/docker-for-java/tree/master/chapter2
```

the run the following command

```
docker run -it --name=wf -p 8080:8080 -v /home/admin/webapp.war:/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/webapp.war jboss/wildfly
```

it giving me permission denied on webapp.war

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0008: Failed checking whether /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/webapp.war was a complete zip: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/webapp.war (Permission denied)
```

How can I give permission to wepapp.war file without any changes made in dockerfile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try instead making your own image, as suggested in [`jboss-dockerfiles/wildfly` issue 19](https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/wildfly/issues/19)

> There are two way to fix it:
>
> Change the owner of the file after adding it to the image with chown (but this is ugly as hell...)

```
FROM jboss/wildfly
ADD your-awesome-app.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/ 
USER root
RUN chown jboss:jboss /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/*
USER jboss
```

> Change the permissions on the host's your-awesome-app.war file:
>
> ```
> chmod 755 your-awesome-app.war
> ```
>
> This will make it readable to the jboss user inside of the container and it'll be able to unpack it.

Comment: How to run `chmod 755 your-awesome-app.war` inside docker container ?

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor If you build your own image as suggested, you won't have to. If you don't, try the chown locally, before mounting that file.

Comment: could not get you. I have taken the image from docker hub. now what I need to do ?

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor for testing, you write your own Dockerfile as described in the answer, docker build it, and run it (without mounting your file as a volume, since it would have been copied directly in your custom image)